# How can I see output from a Brython script on the page? Why doesn't `print` work?

Tags: python, brython

I try to use Brython. I have a Python script (test.py) and I would like to display the result of this script in the browser.

I have tried :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="brython.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="brython()">
<script type="text/python" src="test.py"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my script is :

```
x = int(input("Value: "))
x = pow(x,2)
print("Result: " + str(x))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot display the result in the browser. Is there something missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Brython, `print` displays in the browser console.

If you want to write the result in the HTML document:

```
from browser import document

x = int(input("Value: "))
x = pow(x, 2)

document <= "Result: " + str(x)
```

[edit] Another option is to set `sys.stdout` to an object with a `write()` method, for instance `document` in module **browser** :

```
from browser import document
import sys

sys.stdout = document
print("Hello", "world !")
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But, if I want to display everything in the HTML document whatever the code, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: If the question is how to display with the `print()` function, like in standard Python, you can redirect `sys.stdout` to an object with a
`write` method, eg `document` in module __browser__

Answer (score 3):

Add an id='fish' whatever for  tag and then overwrite it in python:

```
<body id='fish' onload='brython()'>
```

and then:

```
d = document['fish']
d.clear()
d <= "Result: %s" % str(x)
```

Note that you need to call element .clear() first, **<=** is the same as Javascript .appendChild(), see the documentation: https://brython.info/static_doc/en/cookbook/content_in_div.html

If you want to see it in proper XHTML page, don't replace the whole body but just one div-element/tag for example. Or overwrite the whole body with all needed XHTML tags.